# How to fix dropdown menu hover not woking

Tags: css, angular

I try to make dropdown menu but it only works click event, hover event but do not work. Anyone can help me why my code does not work? This is my code below:

=======================================================

**html code**

```css
.topnav {
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.topnav a:active,
a:focus {
  background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.is-active {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.m-dropdown-menu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" routerLink="home">Home</a>
  <a [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" routerLink="about">About</a>
  <a [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" routerLink="contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="m-dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a routerLink="#">Reactive form</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if my english is bad. Thank you very so much.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove

`overflow:hidden` from `top-nav` and `float:left` from `a` element

so your css will look like

```
.topnav {
  color:white;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

.topnav a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color:black;
}

.topnav a:active, a:focus {
  background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.is-active {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color:white;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.m-dropdown-menu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1svp9o0x/)

Comment: If you move the cursor from **parent** to **submenu** the **submenu** disappeared. Thanks

Comment: @BatHuDaiDe can you specify how your accepted ans change after 5 months

Answer (score 1):

I Just update your code structure with few **CSS** changes. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.topnav {
  color:white;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

.topnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.topnav ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.topnav ul li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.topnav a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color:black;
}

.topnav a:active, a:focus {
  background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

.is-active {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color:white;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" routerLink="home">Home</a>
    </li>  
    <li>
      <a [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" routerLink="about">About</a>
    </li>  
    <li>
      <a [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" routerLink="contact">Contact</a>
    </li>  
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a routerLink="#">Reactive form</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ">" in css.

example:

```
.topnav > a:hover {
  background-color:black;
}
```